# javascript getting data attribute, using loop not working

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to fetch the "data-number" of my each element using core javascript. i am no able to use the jquery here, because i am editing a plugin.

but i am not able to fetch the data

html:

```
<ul>
    <li data-number="2" class="number">1</li>
    <li class="number">2</li>
    <li class="number">3</li>
</ul>
```

js:

```
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('.'+number)[i].getAttribute("data-number");
    console.log(x); // i am not getting the result.
}
```

[here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VasTK/)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the dot if you use `getElementsByClassName` and if `name` is "number" :

```
document.getElementsByClassName(name)
```

You seem to confuse it with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) which takes a CSS selector as argument.

In your fiddle you also forget to define name :

```
var name = "number";
```

<kbd>**[Fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eeDqL/)**</kbd>

Comment: thnaks for your immediate help.

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` takes the name of a class, not a selector.

```
document.getElementsByClassName('number')
```

It would also be good to simply iterate over the elements.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('number');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  var x = elements[i].getAttribute('data-number');
  console.log(x);
}
```